# How to duplicate image when clicked in Processing

Tags: java, arrays, function, processing, pde

I am trying to make a simple fly swatting game for a school assignment. I need to make it so that when I click the mouse on a fly, It will replace the image with one of a squished fly, then generate a one new fly in a random position. I have achieved the first part, but when I click a fly it generates, multiple new flies and if i click an already squished one it does the same.

```
void collisionDetect(){ //collision detection - detect collision between 
swatter and fly
for(int i=0; i<swat.length;i++){ // bounding box detection
if(0 <= (mouseX-fX[i]) && (mouseX-fX[i]) <= flysize && 0 <= (mouseY-fY[i]) && (mouseY-fY[i])<= flysize ){ // condition should look at location of mouse and individual coordinates in fX and fY
  swat[i] = 1; // swatted
  fX =append(fX, random(flysize, 780)); 
  fY =append(fY, random(flysize, 380));
  swat =append(swat, 0); 
  score++; //increment score
}
}
}
```

This is the function that is triggered when the mouse is pressed, So I'm assuming the issue lies within here.

```
void populate(){ 
for(int i=0;i<fX.length;i++){
if(swat[i]==1){ 

  image(flybye, fX[i], fY[i]);
  flybye.resize(flysize, flysize);
} else { 
  image(fly, fX[i], fY[i]);
  fly.resize(flysize, flysize);
}
}
}
```

This is the function that places the flies based off an initial randomly generated value added to array's fX & fY

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
        PImage fly,flybye,swatter,swatted;
    float[] fX,fY;  
    float[] swat;  
    int score=0;  
    int flysize = 40;

    void setup(){
      size(800,400);
      fX=new float[0];
      fY=new float[0];
      swat=new float[0];

      fX =append(fX, random(flysize, 780)); 
      fY =append(fY, random(flysize, 380));
      swat = append(swat,0); 
    }
    void populate(){ 
      for(int i=0;i<fX.length;i++){
        if(swat[i]==1){ 

          rect(fX[i], fY[i], flysize, flysize);
          fill(50);
        } else { // not swatted
          rect(fX[i], fY[i], flysize, flysize);
          fill(30);
        }
      }
    }

    void collisionDetect(){ 
      for(int i=0; i<swat.length;i++){ 
        if(0 <= (mouseX-fX[i]) && (mouseX-fX[i]) <= flysize && 0 <= (mouseY-fY[i]) && (mouseY-fY[i])<= flysize ){ 
          swat[i] = 1; // swatted
          fX =append(fX, random(flysize, 780)); /
          fY =append(fY, random(flysize, 380));
          swat =append(swat, 0); 
          score++;             }
      }
    }

    void draw(){
      background(255);
      populate();
        if(mousePressed){ 
          collisionDetect();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Here is a kind of example with squares

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Note that this should **not** be your full program. It should just be a simple runnable example that demonstrates the problem. I recommend putting together an example that shows a single rectangle that changes color when you click it.

Comment: Hey kevin, just updated it with a little example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve both of your problems the only thing that you need to do is to add another condition to your `if` statement in `collisionDetected()` where you check that the current fly is not already swatted:

```
&& swat[i]==0
```

Comment: Actually for "efficiency" better to put the swatted check at the beginning of the if statement.